# How to render html in django rest framework

Tags: django-rest-framework

I am still learning `Django REST framework`, strangling with `HTML` templates, please help, not rendering my keywords:

My View

```
class KeywordList(generics.ListAPIView):
    renderer_classes = [TemplateHTMLRenderer]
    template_name = "chapter/blog-post_2.html"
    serializer_class = KeywordSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        detal = self.kwargs['id']
        queryset = Keyword.objects.filter(chapter=detal)
        return Response({'keyword': query set})
```

My Html:

```
<div class="row thumbs gap-xs">
<div class="col-xs-6 thumb list">
<figure >
<figcaption class="text-overlay">
<div class="info">
    {% for keyword in keywords %}
    <a href="#modal-work03" data-toggle="modal"><h4>{{keyword}}</h4> </a>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
</figcaption>
<a href="#modal-work03" data-toggle="modal"><img src="{% static       'chapter/images/art/work17.jpg' %}" alt=""></a>
</figure>
</div>
```

Comment: I would like to suggest that you are probably not using REST correctly.  Django REST Framework is about extracting and inputting _data_, not the presentation and view of the data.  Something downsteam should be formatting it, like a javascript front-end (ReactJS, AngularJS, JQuery, or plain old javascript) or a mobile app or even a desktop app.

Answer (score 0):

In your response you define keyword as `keyword`, but reference it as `keywords` in the template. I think really you should change `keyword` in your response to be `keywords`, as that makes more logical sense in the given situation. With that change, the template should pick up the difference and `for keyword in keywords` should work.

Also in your response, you type `query set` instead of `queryset`. That will break it too.

Try those fixes and see if it works any better.

Comment: This is an error: The response content must be rendered before it can be iterated over.